# PHP date interval - wrong month difference

Tags: php

Have a look at this code:

```
  $first = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', '2001-07');
  $last = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', '1998-06');
  $interval = $first->diff($last);
  echo "m diff: ".$interval->m." y diff: ".$interval->y."\n";
```

The output is **m diff: 0 y diff: 3**

Why does it return a wrong month difference?

Interesting that if I change dates as '2001-08' and '1998-07', it returns a correct month interval ==1.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you add a day (like '2001-07-01' and '1998-06-01' in the format 'Y-m-d'

Comment: Cannot do this, because I take dates from the database and it may contain either the 1st or the last day of the month. In my case the day is irrelevant - only month difference what matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP `DateTime` doesn't handle incomplete datetimes.

`DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', '2011-07')` gives a `DateTime` that has a year of 2011, a month of 7, and a day, hour, minute and second *taken from the current time* (at the moment I write this, `2011-07-31 18:05:47`.

Likewise, `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', '1998-06')` gives a `DateTime` that has a year of 1998, a month of 6, and a day, hour, minute, and second taken from the current time. Since June 31st is a nonexistent date, the result is `1998-07-01 18:05:47` (31 days after the day before June 1st).

The difference between those two dates is then 3 years, 0 months, and 30 days.

In your example of `2001-08` and `1998-07`, both months happen to have a 31st day, so the math comes out correctly. This bug is a difficult one to pin down, because it depends on the date that the code is *run* even though it doesn't obviously appear to.

You could probably fix your code by using a format of `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` and appending `"-01 00:00:00"` to each date you pass to `createFromFormat`, which will anchor the `DateTime` you get back to the beginning of the month.

Comment: Thanks, I have already realized it after digging into the interval object. It seems to be easier to calculate the month difference from the "Y-m" directly as ($y1 * 12 + $m1) - ($2 *12 + $m2)

Comment: @user2723490 that seems reasonable too. I don't see any non-12-month years in the foreseeable future :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, maybe this may help someone out there:

```
$first = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', '2001-07');
$last = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', '1998-06');
$interval = $first->diff($last);
$num_months = (($interval->y) * 12) + ($interval->m);
```

Explanation : convert $interval->y which is the year to months by multiplying it by 12 and add the succeeding months which is $interval->m

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: sorry my bad i modify my answer @NicoHaase

Comment: As this question also holds an accepted answer that is more than eight years old: did you check that to see whether your code also covers this edge case?

Comment: Yeah, this is wrong in exactly the same way that the code in the question is wrong.